# Siamese network, cosine similarity unexpected result?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I was reading more about siamese network and it's use for similarity problems and I've stumbled upon this https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_network/
I was surprised to see both similarities in the result (at the end of the article) so close to 1. Shouldn't negative similarity be more close to 0 and only positive closer to 1 if distance is cosine? Difference is only after 3rd decimal, both are 0.99... I tried it on my own and I get similar results for different samples. Also tried using MobileNet for base cnn instead of resnet. Getting similar results. That would mean that model sees everything as very similar? Did I understand that correctly? Is there anything wrong in the code that stands out, or is it just architecture/hyperparameters problem, or maybe dataset...?